# My program runs both "if statements" even if they are not correct. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

I am doing a program that will convert units from Imperial to Metric, and vice versa. So far, I have only gotten to the temperature conversions. When I run the code, it works fine until it gets to the if statements for "if temputit == ____. No matter what I input, even if it is gibberish, it will still run the Fahrenheit statement (The top one). Here is my code:

```
unit = input(print("What would you like to convert (Temperature, Distance, Length, Wheight, Volume)? "))
if unit == 'Temperature':
    tempunit = input(print('Do you want to convert Celsius or Fahrenheit?'))
    if tempunit == "Fahrenheit" or "fahrenheit":
        ftemp = int(input(print("Type the number you want to convert: ")))
        ftemp_new = (ftemp - 32) * 5/9
        print(ftemp_new, "°C")
    elif tempunit == "Celsius" or "celsius":
        print("ok")
```

Comment: `tempunit == "Fahrenheit" or tempunit=="fahrenheit"` change it to like this, same for celsius check too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if tempunit == "Fahrenheit" or "fahrenheit":
```

This line of code translates to `if tempunit == "Fahrenheit" or "fahrenheit" is True`. The second part is always true, hence the `if` block is always executed. See https://realpython.com/python-boolean/ for details.

To fix this, you can do one of the following:

1. `tempunit == "Fahrenheit" or tempunit == "fahrenheit"`
2. `tempunit in ["Fahrenheit", "fahrenheit"]`
3. `tempunit.lower() == "fahrenheit"`

Answer (score 4):

When you do the line `if tempunit == "Fahrenheit" or "fahrenheit":` , the second part does not evaluate to if tempunit is equal to 'fahrenheit', it evaluates to fahreneit the string. And a string will always be true so the code will always execute

Try this code to fix it

```
unit = input(print("What would you like to convert (Temperature, Distance, Length, Wheight, Volume)? "))
if unit == 'Temperature':
    tempunit = input(print('Do you want to convert Celsius or Fahrenheit?'))
    if tempunit == "Fahrenheit" or tempunit == "fahrenheit":
        ftemp = int(input(print("Type the number you want to convert: ")))
        ftemp_new = (ftemp - 32) * 5/9
        print(ftemp_new, "°C")
    elif tempunit == "Celsius" or tempunit == "celsius":
        print("ok")
```

Comment: What does your answer say that mine doesn’t?

Comment: I am sorry. I was writing my answer when you were writing yours, then I left to tinkle and when I completed my answer, I saw you had already posted it. You know it is possible for 2 people to give an answer. That doesnt mean you will downvote my answer. I upvoted your answer because it works just as fine

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me.

Comment: Actually a string is not always True.  "" evaluates to False.  Try bool("") or if "": print("True") to verify.  Regardless, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
if "fahrenheit":
```

is the same as

```
if bool("fahrenheit"):
```

is the same as

```
if "fahrenheit" != "":
```

So casting a string to a bool is effectively the same as comparison to inequality with an empty string.

```
if tempunit == "Fahrenheit" or tempunit == "fahrenheit":
```

is the correct code.  Trying to do something like constructing a list and using the in operator or constructing a new string by calling .lower() will be slightly slower do to memory allocation from object construction.